# How to fix DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL Angular HttpClient when calling a third party server/api?

Tags: javascript, angular, xmlhttprequest

I am getting the following error:

`DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL`

when executing a `GET` request to debounce.com

```
import{HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

export {ThisClass} {

constructor(private http:HttpClient){
}

validateEmailBounce(email) {
    const url = 'https://api.debounce.io/v1/?api=my_api_key&email=' + email;
    console.log(url); // https://api.debounce.io/v1/?api=my_api_key&email=someone@email.com
    return this.http.get(url);
  }
}
```

Comment: if you use localhost then only use http:// before your localhost

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Failed to execute open on XMLHttpRequest: Invalid URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42461174/angular-2-failed-to-execute-open-on-xmlhttprequest-invalid-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to try encoding the URL arguments.

```
const url = 'https://api.debounce.io/v1/?api=my_api_key&email=' + encodeURIComponent(email);
```

Docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent