# Trying to make my delete button working in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can someone find the bug in my code? I'm trying to make a delete button work that delete a specific challenge that has been clicked.

**The error in the console:**

xhr.js:178 DELETE http://localhost:3000/allchallenges/5eb4398f2650390017030bcf 404 (Not Found)

---

**Front-end component that has a delete button**

```
import React from 'react'
import DefaultLayout from "../layout/Default"
import Challengebox from '../components/Challengebox'
import axios from "axios";

class Allchallenges extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
           challenges: []
        }

        this.onDelete=this.onDelete.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/allchallenges`,
            withCredentials: true
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            let challengeslist = response.data;
            this.setState({challenges: challengeslist})
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("You've made an error charles: ",error)
        })
    }

    onDelete(challengeId){
        axios
        .delete(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/allchallenges/${challengeId}`)
        .then(response => {
            this.props.history.push("/allchallenges")
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <DefaultLayout>
                <div className="challengeoverviewlist">
                    <h1>All challenges</h1>   

                    <div className="challengeboxes">

                    {    
                    this.state.challenges.map(challenge => 
                        (
                            <div className="totalbox" key={challenge._id}>

                                <Challengebox 
                                    key={challenge._id} 
                                    id={challenge._id} 
                                    title={challenge.title} 
                                    description={challenge.description}
                                />

                                <button onClick={() => this.onDelete(challenge._id)}>
                                    Delete
                                </button>

                            </div>
                        ))                                                                      
                    }

                    </div>

                </div>    
            </DefaultLayout>
        )
    }
}

export default Allchallenges
```

---

**My api:**

```
//request challenges
router.get("/allchallenges", (req,res) => {
  Challenge
  .find()
  .then(response => {
    res.json(response)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    res.json(error)
  })
})

//delete challenge
router.delete("/allchallenges", (req,res) => {
  Challenge
  .find()
  .then(response => {
    res.json(response)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    res.json(error)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> xhr.js:178 DELETE
>   http://localhost:3000/allchallenges/5eb4398f2650390017030bcf 404 (Not
>   Found)

404 : not found - Error clearly state that the api with that path not exists

So, the issue with your express API routing :

Change this:

```
router.delete("/allchallenges",
```

To:

```
router.delete("/allchallenges/:id",
```

> NOTE : You can access the params with `req.params`

Comment: Thanks I changed it. This is the error I get now: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL
    at dispatchXhrRequest (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:318:13)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at xhrAdapter (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:301:10)
    at dispatchRequest (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:924:10)

Comment: @CharlieVdb, so your question error is solved, now that is something is react related

Comment: What is the value of `process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE`

Comment: What do you mean? Any idea what the error could be?

Comment: @CharlieVdb, as long as I know this happens when you are missing `http://` or `https://` in your URL , check that , for ref check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42461174/angular-2-failed-to-execute-open-on-xmlhttprequest-invalid-url

Comment: thanks man where can I find my URL? I have a .env file in back-end and .env.production & .env.development files in my front-end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213558/discussion-between-vivek-doshi-and-charlie-vdb).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to add a route parameter.

```js
router.delete("/allchallenges/:id", (req,res) => {
  Challenge
  .find()
  .then(response => {
    res.json(response)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    res.json(error)
  })
})
```

[Also if you want to delete object and you are using mongoose you have to use Model.findByIdAndDelete](https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/how-to-delete-documents-with-mongoose-235#delete+by+id)

Comment: Thanks I added the parameter and changed find() to findByIdAndDelete(), but still get an error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) + Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL
    at dispatchXhrRequest (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:318:13)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at xhrAdapter (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:301:10)
    at dispatchRequest (http://localhost:3001/static/js/0.chunk.js:924:10)